# How to reconnect to TCP server after network goes down and comes back up again?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a raspberry pi that connects to a TCP server and sends some data every couple of seconds, I want to be able to handle all kind of failures and disconnects, so at the moment I am trying a test where I disconnect the Huawei USB dongle that I am connecting through.

I have a thread that runs in the background and check the connection periodically. The code does not reconnect when I remove the USB dongle and plug it back in sometime later, I need help on how to make this more robust. At the moment on the server side I see that after I plug back in the USB dongle I see the client connect but immediately disconnect from it.

The thread is called KeepSocketOpen and inside here I call a ping function to 8.8.8.8 to see if the connection is still active and here is my code, I'm kind of new to socket programming so excuse the mess:

```
int ping(char *ipaddr)
{
    char *command = NULL;
    FILE *fp;
    int x, match=0;
    char* result = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    asprintf (&command, "%s %s -p 50 -r 3", "fping", ipaddr);
    //printf ("%s %s -q 2>&1", "fping", ipaddr);
    fp = popen(command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute fping command\n");
        free(command);
        return -1;
    }

    while(getline(&result, &len, fp) != -1) {
        fputs(result, stdout);
        //printf("%s",result);
    }


    for(x=0;x<len;x++)
    {
        if(x>5 && result[x]=='e'&& result[x-1]=='v'&&  result[x-2]=='i'&& result[x-3]=='l'&& result[x-4]=='a')
        {
            match=1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(match==0)
        sleep(5);

    free(result);
    fflush(fp);
    if (pclose(fp) != 0) {
        perror("Cannot close stream.\n");
    }
    free(command);
    //printf("%s\r\n",result);

    if(match==0)
        return -1;
    else 
        return 1;
}

void* KeepSocketOpen(void *arg)
{
    pthread_t id= pthread_self();
    char tcprxbuff[1024];
    int numbytes, status=0,attempts,reuse=1;
    struct timeval timeout={0};

    timeout.tv_sec=10;
    timeout.tv_usec=0;

    printf("in sock thread\r\n");

    while(1)
    {
        if(is_socket_connected==0)
        {
            sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
            addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            addr.sin_port = htons(34879);
            addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("X.X.X.X");
            attempts=0;
            setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDTIMEO,(char *)&timeout,sizeof(timeout));
            setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,(char *)&timeout,sizeof(timeout));
            setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&reuse,sizeof(reuse));

            status=connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &addr,sizeof (addr));

            // wait for 5s and see if the socket has connected
            do
            {
                delay(5);
            }
            while(errno && attempts++<1000);

            if (attempts >=1000 || errno) // this is the fail case
            {
                printf("socket not connected %s\r\n",strerror(errno));
                is_socket_connected=0;
                close(sock);
                //shutdown(sock,SHUT_RDWR);
                sleep(30);
            }
            else
            {
                // fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
                printf("socket reconnected %d,%s\r\n",attempts,strerror(errno));
                is_socket_connected=1;
                write(sock, "HI FROM RASPI", strlen("HI FROM RASPI"));
            }       
        }
        else
        {
            numbytes=read(sock,tcprxbuff,sizeof(tcprxbuff));
            if(numbytes==0)// if this is zero, socket was closed by server
            {
                is_socket_connected=0;
                while(close(sock)==-1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("socket connected:%d\r\n",numbytes);
                status = ping("8.8.8.8");
                if (status!=-1) {
                    printf("socket still connected:%d\r\n",status);
                    is_socket_connected=1;
                } else {
                    printf("socket disconnected:%d\r\n",status);
                    is_socket_connected=0;
                    //shutdown(sock,SHUT_RDWR);

                    while(close(sock)==-1);

                }
            }
            sleep(30);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May we assume the title should read: "*How to reconnect to TCP server after network went down **and came back up again?***" Else the answer is simple: "Never"

Comment: Yes smarty pants, fixed it now

Comment: "*on the server side [...] I see the client connect but immediately disconnect from it.* After that, does the server go into `accept()`ing again? Or is the server capable to server multiple connections in parallel anyway?

Comment: My server can accept multiple clients and it detects when a client disconnects aswell.

Comment: An important detail: `errno` *only* holds a defined value if the function setting it failed. In the case of your call to `connect()` by the `do`-loop look like this: `while((-1 != status) && attempts++<1000) { delay(5); }`. And the following `if`statement to look like: ` if (attempts >=1000 || (-1 == status))`

Comment: Also for a blocking socket, which is the default and what you use, `connect()` blocks until the socket is connected. So this waiting is useless any ways.

Comment: Same for `close()`. Looping around it until it returns `-1` gains nothing.

Comment: "*The code does not reconnect when I remove the USB dongle*" I strongly assume that is because it is stuck in `ping()`is loop around `getline()`. You want to uncomment this line `//printf("%s",result);` to prove this.

Comment: [Above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323865/how-to-reconnect-to-tcp-server-after-network-goes-down-and-comes-back-up-again?noredirect=1#comment101148698_57323865) this "*... call to connect() by the `do`-loop ...*" should read: "*... call to connect() change the `do`-loop to look ...*"

Comment: And here is how you test your code with network outages: [GitHub | Comcast](https://github.com/tylertreat/Comcast). The project is described as *"Simulating shitty network connections so you can build better systems"*.